# Merge table in table Lua

Tags: soap, lua

How can i merge a LUA-table with variable lenght into an other LUA table.

In a FOR-LOOP i want to search for records (plunr and pluname) and placed in a table.
If each record is placed in the table, i will merge this table in an other " request-table"

The problem is that only the last record is being sent to the webserver.

```
 for rrplu in receipt:getPLUs() do
   local plunr = rrplu:getPLUNo();
   local pluname = rrplu:getName();
   plutable = { tag = "hot1:TicketDetail",
                                    { tag = "hot1:PLU", plunr},
                                    { tag = "hot1:Description", pluname},
                                }     

 end;

 local soap_client = vpos.communication.SOAPClient (http)
 local request = {
    url = urlHTTPS,
    soapaction = "http://blablabla.com/IXmlPosService/Charge",
    namespace = {hot="http://blablabla.com/",
    hot1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BlaBla.Web.DataContracts"},
    method = "hot:Charge",
    body =  { tag = "hot:Charge",
                    { tag = "hot:authentication",
                    { tag = "hot1:Token", TokenValue},
                    },
                    { tag = "hot:request",
                    { tag = "hot1:PosDate", datum},
                    { tag = "hot1:TicketDetails",
                    plutable
                    },
                    },
                    }
                }
   result, err, err_string = soap_client:call (request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each pass through the loop sets `plutable` to a new table. You probably want to insert into a new or existing table.

Replace `plutable =` with

```
plutable = plutable or {}
table.insert(plutable, { 
    tag = "hot1:TicketDetail",
    { tag = "hot1:PLU", plunr },
    { tag = "hot1:Description", pluname }})
```